# OGRE No suitable conversion function exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, ogre

I'm having a hard time trying to get an app to compile in Visual Studio 2013. I've solved a good amount of errors but I can't find a solution for the last one.

here it is:

```
void Application::setupRenderSystem() {
mState->dumpValues();

String val = mState->getStringValue("renderSystem");
RenderSystemList *renderSystems = mRoot->getAvailableRenderers();
RenderSystemList::iterator r_it;    

bool renderSystemFound = false;
for (r_it = renderSystems->begin(); r_it != renderSystems->end(); r_it++) {
    RenderSystem *tmp = *r_it;
    std::string rName(tmp->getName());

    // returns -1 if string not found
    if ((int)rName.find(val) >= 0) {
        mRoot->setRenderSystem(*r_it);
        renderSystemFound = true;
        break;
    }
}        
if (!renderSystemFound) {
    OGRE_EXCEPT(0, "Specified render system (" + val + ") not found, exiting...", "Application")
}
```

}

Visual Studio indicates that the line `RenderSystemList *renderSystems = mRoot->getAvailableRenderers();` is the problem, especially `mRoot`

Here is the error I get:
**error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const Ogre::RenderSystemList' to 'Ogre::RenderSystemList *'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getAvailableRenderers` method doesn't return a pointer to a `RenderSystemList`. You'd want to have the value stored in a reference to a `RenderSystemList`:

```
RenderSystemList const& renderSystems = mRoot->getAvailableRenderers();
```

Comment: Thx. Now the problem is that `renderSystems->begin()` and `renderSystems->end()` are supposed to be pointers. Here is the error I get: **Expression must have a pointer type**

Comment: renderSystems is not a pointer. You use `.` instead of `->`. The `->` operator is only for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The Ogre API says:

```
const RenderSystemList &    getAvailableRenderers (void)
```

So it returns a const reference and not a pointer.
Modify your code like this

```
const RenderSystemList &renderSystems = mRoot->getAvailableRenderers();
```